# ReCaptcha does not load / show in IE but works perfectly in Chrome and safari

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

On http://www.dutchsupercross.nl/inschrijven I implemented a captcha at the bottom. But does not seem to work in Internet Explorer.

It also looks like that IE does not like to load HTTPS because i do not see that this file is loaded in the developer tools (Network) When i change it to HTTP it seems to load the javascript but still nothing shows up.

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: may we know which IE version are you talking about?

Comment: I am using IE 11 (11.0.10240.16384)

Comment: if it doesn't work so don't use it, there are many other ways to stop bots from sending forms like [Honeypot](https://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/01/honeypot-technique-fast-easy-spam-prevention/)

Answer (score 0):

I checked the website in my Chrome, Mozilla, IE, and Yandex browsers and it worked pretty well. Sometimes the browsers have something about the compatibility.

There is a good documentation in google's recaptcha website. Check the following link and apply the steps under the section "reCAPTCHA isn't displaying properly on Internet Explorer, what do I do?"

The link is: [Google reCAPTCHA website](https://support.google.com/recaptcha/?hl=en)

Comment: Yeah it is weird I tried that option too but without any luck unfortunately. Google was not even in that list.

I also tried calling the javascript with the callback but also that did not have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find nearest possible issue,
I don't rely much on dealing browser specific without encourage the user to update their browser.
Since the implication may not only issue like this.
Based on SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821645/at-which-point-do-you-decide-to-stop-supporting-older-browsers),
we won't and we can't agreed all of that. Which if we decide support IE we should drop IE older than 11 now on.
Which also proper and diligent decision that you take, base on [microsoft official documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support)

Which i want to highlight is when we decide browser support we also should take care of the browser ecosystem.
That you probably can upgrade the jquery version from 2.1.0 to 2.1.4 which from semantic versioning it's just the patch, that hopefully doesn't break your code.
But futhermore you should include upgrade the minor patch to your working schedule which suit your need and priority.
Frankly i can't find the glance on the change log, so i can't guarantee that **this work**.
But personally this is better than repetition same debugging process that the result is uncertain.

Action step:

1. Make sure follow installation recapcha properly.

   1. Which display mode you choose to display the [widget](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) ?

      - Its also have different behaviour.
      - Recaptcha doc already notice that automatic render is the easiest way. Use this if you don't, but more importantly change this display mode if this
        can fix your issue.
2. It possible jquery bug, but be aware directing it. (Possibilities unreported, not yet fixed, fixed on certain version).
   3 Most possible nearest bug for me [1764](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1764), [3041](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3041) since it will render through iframe

   1. Fixed on certain version :

      - Work on your code with jQuery [changelog](https://gist.github.com/teppeis/9264080)
      - Work on your code, while upgrading it. (have draw back on it's own).
   2. Not yet Fixed.

      - seek out on jquery [issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+IE11)
      - seek out on [bug](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues?q=label%3ABug+IE11+is%3Aclosed)
      - Issue and Bug are differs.
      - Follow framework or lib specific for re
   3. Unreported and Untracked

      - It's a bit hard to recaptcha since